Reusing pip cache. Pipenv install results in constantly growing cache
I need to upload pipenv cache to S3 bucket after installing the dependencies as part of the CI run.
I set PIPENV_CACHE_DIR env var to a path where to store cache and run installation command as follows:
export PIPENV_CACHE_DIR=$env.WORKSPACE/.pipenv-cache
pipenv install --deploy

But with every run the cache that is uploaded to the bucket grows by ~same size. Adding --clear option doesn't change it.
I tried to run pipenv commands locally and check size of cache folders (under /Library/Caches/pip  and .pipenv-cache set by PIPENV_CACHE_DIR).
pipenv install --deploy -> cache folders don't grow.
pipenv lock -> /Library/Caches/pip/http grew by 16M, .pipenv-cache grew by 2M.
What causes this behavior of growing cache and is there any solution to prevent it?
versions:

python3.9
pipenv 2023.7.11
pip 23.0.1

